# Pointers with structs

Tags: c, opengl

So I've been studying C programming for a little while now, and while I can understand the basic concept behind pointers, I'm still having a lot of trouble implementing them in my programming, especially when it comes to passing them across multiple different structs. For example, I have this code snippet (I've omitted the non-relevant parts):

**main.c**

```
Globals globals;

static void display(Globals *globals)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(globals->trees[i].pos.x, globals->trees[i].pos.y, globals->trees[i].pos.z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(globals->trees[i].pos.x + 5, globals->trees[i].pos.y, globals->trees[i].pos.z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(globals->trees[i].pos.x + 5, globals->trees[i].pos.y + 5, globals->trees[i].pos.z);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(globals->trees[i].pos.x, globals->trees[i].pos.y + 5, globals->trees[i].pos.z);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

**globals.h**

```
struct Globals
{
    Tree *trees; // tree array
};
```

**globals.c**

```
void initGlobals(Globals *globals)
{
     initTrees(&globals->trees, &globals->grid);
}
```

**tree.h**

```
#pragma once

#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "utils.h"

    typedef struct Tree Tree;
    typedef struct Grid Grid;

    struct Tree
    {
        vec3f pos;
    };

    void initTrees(Tree *trees, Grid *grid);

#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**trees.c**

```
#include "tree.h"

void initTrees(Tree *trees, Grid *grid)
{
    trees = (Tree *) calloc(20, sizeof(Tree));
    if (trees == NULL)
    {
        printf("COULD NOT ALLOCATE.");
        exit(1);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    float x_rand, z_rand;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        x_rand = rand() & 50;
        z_rand = rand() & 50;
        Tree tree;
        tree.pos = cVec3f(x_rand, accumHeight(grid, x_rand, z_rand) + 1, z_rand);
        trees[i] = tree;
    }
}
```

At the moment, I'm trying to add a set of tree structs to a tree array and then draw them one by one in main.c, but I'm getting an unhandled exception. I'm almost 100% sure that it's because there's something wrong with my pointer syntax, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: where does the exception occur and is the pointer you are trying to access at that point initialized?

Comment: I don't see a declaration for `Grid` or its initialization anywhere. Also, `Globals` has no member `grid` to be initialized.

Comment: You declared a global with the same name as some function arguments, that's dangerous.

Comment: `rand() & 50` Huh what's this supposed to do? Didn't you mean `% 50`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the address of a pointer (and thus a pointer-to-pointer) to a function expecting a single-indirection pointer.

Anytime you see this:

```
void foo(Something* p)
{
    p = some allocation function
    ...
}
```

raise your brow, because its likely going to result in a memory leak, if not an outright invalid indirection, (and likely both).

In your case,

```
void initTrees(Tree *trees, Grid *grid);
```

is being invoked with

```
//globals.c
void initGlobals(Globals *globals)
{
     initTrees(&globals->trees, &globals->grid);
}
```

where `globals->trees` is declared as:

```
//globals.h
struct Globals
{
    Tree *trees; // tree array
};
```

The type of what is being passed is `Tree**`, yet the function expects `Tree*` (incorrectly, but we'll get to that in a minute). The pattern I described in the outset of this answer is repeated here:

```
void initTrees(Tree *trees, Grid *grid)
{
    trees = (Tree *) calloc(20, sizeof(Tree)); // LOOK HERE
    if (trees == NULL)
    {
        printf("COULD NOT ALLOCATE.");
        exit(1);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    float x_rand, z_rand;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        x_rand = rand() & 50;
        z_rand = rand() & 50;
        Tree tree;
        tree.pos = cVec3f(x_rand, accumHeight(grid, x_rand, z_rand) + 1, z_rand);
        trees[i] = tree;
    }
}
```

All this does is allocate some memory and use a `trees` as a value-parameter (the value is the address of... something... but thats not relevant; that address is lost the moment you make that assignment).

`initTrees`, needs a double-indirection pointer `Tree **` and should dereference it to save the proper data being allocated:

```
void initTrees(Tree **trees, Grid *grid)
{
    Tree *res = calloc(20, sizeof(Tree)); // NOTE: local used for allocation
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        printf("COULD NOT ALLOCATE.");
        exit(1);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    float x_rand, z_rand;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        x_rand = rand() & 50;
        z_rand = rand() & 50;
        res[i].pos = cVec3f(x_rand, accumHeight(grid, x_rand, z_rand) + 1, z_rand);
    }

    // save result
    *trees = res;   // NOTE: save to out-parameter
}
```

Or something similar. Note your compiler should be screaming at your about passing an invalid parameter (types mismatching).  Also, note the removal of the `calloc` cast, which isn't needed (nor advised) in C programs.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had something to do with my pointers. Guess I've still got a lot to learn about how pointers work :/